# I followed the code in my Python guide book yet running it through Visual Code Studios, the code will not perform at all

Tags: python

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256 as SHA


class myDES():
    def __init__(self, keytext, ivtext):
        hash = SHA.new()
        hash.update(keytext.encode('utf-8'))
        key = hash.digest()
        self.key=key[:24]

        hash.update(ivtext.encode('utf-8'))
        iv = hash.digest()
        self.iv=iv[:8]

    def enc(self, plaintext):
        des3 = DES3.new(self.key,DES3.MODE_CBC,self.iv)
        encmsg = des3.encrypt(plaintext.encode())
        return encmsg

    def dec(self, ciphertext):
        des3 = DES3.new(self.key,DES3.MODE_CBC,self.iv)
        decmsg = des3.decrypt(ciphertext)
        return decmsg


def main():
    keytext = 'samsjang'
    ivtext = '1234'
    msg = 'python3x'

    myCipher = myDES(keytext, ivtext)
    ciphered = myCipher.enc(msg)
    deciphered = myCipher.dec(ciphered)
    print('ORIGINAL: %s' % msg)
    print('CIPHERED: %s' % ciphered)
    print('DECIPHERED: %s' % deciphered)


main()
```

This is the current code that I am trying to run through Visual Code Studios. I have a guidebook about learning information about Cryptology through Python, and I followed the book as it told me to write some codes. Most were successful, but this particular code did not run for some reason. It doesn't even show an error, just saying 'PS C:\doit> & C:/Users/ksm97/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/doit/3desformsg.py' while not performing any action. Can somebody please help me? I am quite new to coding btw, so please take note of that.

Comment: Fixed your code formatting. As your indentation was kind of broken and the `main()` function was calling itself as part of the class, this might already do the trick for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! It did the trick.

Comment: But I have another question. Why did it not show the error and just didn't perform anything at all?

Comment: It ran the program, but the `main()` function outputting text to your terminal was never executed as it was never called.